# IPSEC configuration - Error writing to socket: operation not permitted

Tags: linux-networking, ipsec, strongswan

Hello I am trying to set up IPSEC for the first time and am running into an issue. I think on the first phase something is wrong but I can't seem to really figure out why I have these in the log:

```
Feb  2 12:47:59 15[NET] <xxxx|1> sending packet: from ourip[500] to destip[500] (976 bytes)
Feb  2 12:47:59 09[NET] sending packet: from ourip[500] to destip[500]
Feb  2 12:47:59 09[NET] error writing to socket: Operation not permitted
Feb  2 12:47:59 02[JOB] next event in 3s 999ms, waiting
Feb  2 12:47:59 15[MGR] <xxxx|1> checkin IKE_SA xxxx[1]
Feb  2 12:47:59 15[MGR] <xxxx|1> check-in of IKE_SA successful.
Feb  2 12:48:03 02[JOB] got event, queuing job for execution
Feb  2 12:48:03 02[JOB] no events, waiting
Feb  2 12:48:03 08[MGR] checkout IKE_SA
Feb  2 12:48:03 08[MGR] IKE_SA xxxx[1] successfully checked out
Feb  2 12:48:03 08[IKE] <xxxx|1> retransmit 1 of request with message ID 0
Feb  2 12:48:03 08[NET] <xxxx|1> sending packet: from ourip[500] to destip[500] (976 bytes)
Feb  2 12:48:03 08[MGR] <xxxx|1> checkin IKE_SA xxxx[1]
Feb  2 12:48:03 08[MGR] <xxxx|1> check-in of IKE_SA successful.
Feb  2 12:48:03 09[NET] sending packet: from ourip[500] to destip[500]
Feb  2 12:48:03 09[NET] error writing to socket: Operation not permitted
```

I'm not really sure how to resolve this. 
does Operation not permitted imply that a firewall is blocking ?

i have changed some sentitive data in this log

Comment: looks like permission issue... are you running ipsec as a root user or like `sudo ipsec`? normal user cannot open ports below 1024

Comment: Also check the firewall rules.

Comment: I'm running it as root,..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

THere were some firewall rules that disabled writing to the socket.